# Missing data paired samples t-test

Tags: t-test, missing-data, paired-comparisons

I have a list of insurance policies that filed claims in pre/post periods. I am trying to test whether the average cost of insurance claims per policy varied. Some of my policies don't have any claims in pre, but have some claims in post.

Should I make the average claim cost of these policies zero or should I ignore the whole policy? Or something else?

Comment: Do you have any other variables/covariates available to you that might enable to you to predict the missing values?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check whether the average of pre and post claims cost of insurance claims per policy varied **for claim(s) rise**, then you should ignore.

&

If you want to check whether average of pre and post claims cost of insurance claims per policy varied **for policies exposed to risk**,then you should not ignore.

Then, use Paired t-test.